# Differences in query result format from DocDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm wrapping access to a DocDB collection in a C# class and are experiences some pain in mapping the more advanced queries. While trying to debug using the Query Explorer I noticed some differences in the json returned:

```
select * from collection
```

will return

```
[{ "id" : "1", "names" : [ {"name" : "first"}, {"name" : "second"}]}]
```

while

```
select c from collection c
```

will return

```
[{ "c" : { "id" : "1", "names" : [ {"name" : "first"}, {"name" : "second"}]}}]
```

Please notice how the results are nested below a "c" property!

This difference seems to cause issues when I need to create queries that uses named selects and having the c# library map results back into a type. An example of such a query is

```
select c from collection c join n in c.names WHERE n.name = "first"
```

This query MUST use the 'c' for selection (* is not allowed) so the internal mapping returns the correct number of results but each returned item is not mapped (likely because it expects the json properties at the topmost level and not beneath a "c" property).

Does anyone know how I can get the DocumentQuery C# api (from nuget version 1.5.3) to understand that results to map are nested below a named result property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading under the [SELECT clause](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/#select-clause) I found the **VALUE** keyword that just returns the json which makes the C# driver happy again.

So my query should end up reading

```
select value c from collection c join n in c.names WHERE n.name = "first"
```